# How to run ActionScript in Sublime Text?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sublimetext3

I am using a package that provides multiple features for working with Actionscript 3 projects in Sublime Text 2. And while it's working perfect, I can't run the code in the Sublime Text.

I saw in some places that you need to go to Tools > Build System > choose your build (here would appear the action script).

But it doesn't appear, and I can't run the code, giving me the follow error :

> No Build System

How can I make this work ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the existing [Action Script 3](https://github.com/calvinwylie/sublimetext-actionscript-3/tree/master/Support) package for Sublime Text, or create your own custom build system.

**Example**:

```
{
    "selector": "source.actionscript",
    "cmd": [
        "mxmlc", 
        "${file}",
        "-library-path+=${project_path}/libs",
        "-output", "${project_path}/bin/${project_base_name}.swf",
        "-debug=false",
        "-static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true"
    ],
    "file_regex": "^(.+?)\\(([0-9]+)\\): col: (([0-9]+))(.*)$"
}
```

Make sure you got [Adobe Flex SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html) (or [Apache Flex SDK](http://flex.apache.org/installer.html)) installed and that `mxmlc` is in your [PATH environmental variable](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them/284351#284351). Alternatively, you can provide its path in the build file (see the [documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/exec.html) for details).

Comment: If I save as .sfw, it doesn't work, and If I save as .as says that it has no building system. And I placed the mxmlc.exe in the PATH, but still not working. Why is this happening ?

Comment: I will try here, I come back later to say if it worked.